# How to manage tcp node-red connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, node-red

An example of what you want to get:

1. A new tcp session is created.
2. On it I receive data about the client
3. I remember that there is such a session and it belongs to this client.
4. Occurs inject
5. I process json from inject, which contains information - to whom and what.
6. I select the required connection and send the data to it.
   How to do it?

I figured out how to do all this by creating tcp connections in advance with potential customers. And how to do this if the addresses are not known in advance, can anyone connect and transfer the registration information?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you don't.

The TCP nodes only support making connections to addresses that are known at deploy time.